How to restrict web results on spotlight search (iOS 18.1.1)?
I'm trying to block web results on spotlight search using parental controls but I don't see any setting for this within the screen time settings.  I know that in the previous iOS there was a weird issue where you had to turn off screen time in order to turn off web results for spotlight search and then turn it back on to hide the search settings, but now search has its own section and the relevant toggle is visible with screen time enabled so that can't be the issue.
